# Empty variable due to asynchronous callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is some very simplified pseudo-ish code to understand the structure of my code.

What would be a simple approach to solve my asynchronous callback dilemma.
The token will be empty when it's used in requestOption. So the following usage of requestOption will not give any results due to the missing token.

```
var token = ''
var auth1 = someData
var auth2 = someFunc(auth1)
var auth3 = someOtherData
var auth4 = someOtherFunc(auth3)
var finalAuth = someFinalData
var finalAuth2 = finalAuth.someFinalFunc(auth4, cb)
  cb.onSuccess(result)
    token = result.getToken()

var requestOption = {
  someData: ...,
  'authToken': token,
  someMoreData: ...
}
req = request.post(requestOption)
```

There are many solutions and most of them includes using functions to some extend.
Maybe it is useful to modularize the authentication and processing the the requests in another file.

But I would like to keep it simple and not be dependant on something like this

```
var empty = ''
var data = 'xyz'
auth(data, {
    onSuccess: function(res) {
        doSomething(res) 
    }
})

function doSomething(var) {
 // do something
}
```

What I found so far couldn't help me without overcomplicating my code.

Comment: It's really hard to see what you're asking here. The example doesn't look anything like the first example. 

In any case, if the `requestOption` depends on something that is the result of `someFinalFunc` then you have to put it inside the callback. (Or use async/await).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to deal with promises and callbacks then mark your function as async and then await your result, it is syntactic sugar that magically wraps promises for you. When dealing with an async function like a post some will have to wait for the response.

https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

You should include your request logic inside the success callback. In your case, your code with request and request options are executed before setting the value of the token, because auth function is asynchronous and the server need some time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

Basic JavaScript will provide you with three primary options for handling asynchronous behavior.

1. **Callback functions** (what you're doing now)

```js
function callback() {
    console.log('do this');
    setTimeout(() => console.log('later do this'), 2000);
}
callback();
```

---

2. **Promises** - Used to provide a more structured way of handling asynchronous behavior, and cleanup the *callback hell* that starts to form when there is a lot of asynchronous behavior being handled by callback functions.

A promise is declared with a function with two function parameters - resolve and reject. Resolve is used to resolve the promise normally, with a payload as an argument, which then becomes available in a chained `.then( ... )` function. Reject can be used to resolve the promise exceptionally. See [Mozilla docs on Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for further explanation and examples.

```js
function asynchronousFunction() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      return resolve('then do this');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

function promise() {
  console.log('do this');
  asynchronousFunction()
    .then((data) => console.log(data));
};

promise();
```

---

3. **Async/Await** - Essentially syntactic sugar for promises that hides most of the promises code, which can complicate and crowd out internal logic.

```js
function asynchronousFunction() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout( () => {
      return resolve('then do this');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

/**
* async functions implicitly return promises with the return value being the resolved value
await keyword will implicitly unwrap the promise when it resolves and (to some degre) pause execution to until resolution
*/
async function asyncFunction() {
  console.log('do this');
  console.log(await asynchronousFunction());
};

asyncFunction();
```

---

The skinny on it:

1. Callbacks are okay for general purpose stuff, and under the hood this is how things really work. Understanding callbacks is important for understanding JavaScript. However, with a heavily asynchronous application, it can be very difficult to understand the order code executes in, because of the nested behavior.
2. Promises solves the former problem, but adds its own layer of complexity to the code. You should be careful to use promises effectively to make the code more readable. If they are not used well, sometimes they can impede code readability. This is generally better structure than endless callbacks, but still is not nearly as readable and organized as synchronous code.
3. Async/await is fundamentally promises, but hidden from the user. These tools can make your code much easier to read, but you need to fundamentally understand promises to really understand how it works. The big benefit here is that the code begins to look more like synchronous code and it makes it easier to focus on the internal logic rather than the asynchronous behavior.